# How do I solve the error in my C program where time period displays wrong output?

Tags: c, function, time

Basically, I have an interactive C program that is made for reserving classrooms. It has many functionalities like reserving a room, displaying reserved rooms, deleting reserved rooms, and editing reserved room information. After reserving a room, it supposed to be showing appropriate room number, reservation date, start time (check in time), end time (check out time), and the purpose of reservation in 'void DisplayReservations()' function. The problem with my code is that instead of showing appropriate start time period format (am/pm), it always ends up showing wrong output (Ex. ampm). Does anyone know or points out which part of the code causes this kind of error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MaxRooms 8
#define MaxPurpose 100

struct Reservation {
    int RoomNumber, StartTime, StartMin, EndTime, Endmin, m1, d1, year;
    char date[11], purpose[MaxPurpose], ampm[2], ampm1[2];
};

void AddReservation();
void DisplayReservations();
void DeleteReservation();
int CheckOverlap(struct Reservation newReservation);
void EditReservation();

struct Reservation reservations[MaxRooms];
int NumReserves = 0;

int main() {
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 5) {
        printf("Reservation System Menu:\n");
        printf("1. Reserve room\n");
        printf("2. Display all assigned room/s\n");
        printf("3. Delete reservation\n");
        printf("4. Edit reservation\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter number from 1-5\n");
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1) {
            AddReservation();
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            DisplayReservations();
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            DeleteReservation();
        } else if (choice == 4) {
            EditReservation();
        } else if (choice == 5) {
            printf("Exiting program.\n");
        } else {
            printf("Invalid choice. Please enter a valid option.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int CheckOverlap(struct Reservation newReservation) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NumReserves; ++i) {
        if (newReservation.RoomNumber == reservations[i].RoomNumber &&
            newReservation.year == reservations[i].year &&
            newReservation.m1 == reservations[i].m1 &&
            newReservation.d1 == reservations[i].d1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//task 1 if-else
void AddReservation() {
    if (NumReserves >= MaxRooms) {
        printf("No more room for reservations.\n");
        return;
    }

    struct Reservation newReservation;

    while(1){
        printf("\nEnter the room number (Please enter only three(3) digits): ");
        scanf("%d", &newReservation.RoomNumber);

        if(newReservation.RoomNumber < 1000 && newReservation.RoomNumber >= 100){
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
        }
    }

    while(1){
        printf("Enter date of use (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%d/%d/%d", &newReservation.m1,&newReservation.d1,&newReservation.year);

        if(newReservation.m1 > 0 && newReservation.m1 < 13 && newReservation.d1 > 0 && newReservation.d1 <= 31 && newReservation.year > 999 && newReservation.year <= 9999){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong date format\n");
        }
    }

    while(1){
        printf("Enter start time:\n");
        printf("Enter Hours: ");
        scanf("%d", &newReservation.StartTime);
        printf("Enter Minutes: ");
        scanf("%d", &newReservation.StartMin);
        printf("Enter AM/PM: ");
        scanf("%s", newReservation.ampm);

        if(newReservation.StartTime <= 12 && newReservation.StartTime > 0 && newReservation.StartMin <= 59 && newReservation.StartMin > 0){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong time format!\n");
        }
    }

    while(1){
        printf("Enter End time:\n");
        printf("Enter Hours: ");
        scanf("%d", &newReservation.EndTime);
        printf("Enter Minutes: ");
        scanf("%d", &newReservation.Endmin);
        printf("Enter AM/PM: ");
        scanf("%s", newReservation.ampm1);

        if(newReservation.EndTime <= 12 && newReservation.EndTime > 0 && newReservation.Endmin <= 59 && newReservation.Endmin > 0){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong time format!\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Enter purpose of the usage: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(newReservation.purpose, MaxPurpose, stdin);
    newReservation.purpose[strcspn(newReservation.purpose, "\n")] = 0;


    if (CheckOverlap(newReservation)) {
        printf("This reservation conflicts with an existing one and cannot be added.\n");
    } else {
        reservations[NumReserves++] = newReservation;
        printf("\nReservation added successfully.\n\n");
    }
}

void DisplayReservations() {
    printf("\n---- All Reservations ----\n");
    if (NumReserves == 0) {
        printf("No reservations found.\n\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumReserves; ++i) {
            printf("Reservation %d:\n", i + 1);
            printf("Room Number: %d\n", reservations[i].RoomNumber);
            printf("Date: %d/%d/%d\n", reservations[i].m1, reservations[i].d1, reservations[i].year);
            printf("Start Time: %d:%d %s\n", reservations[i].StartTime, reservations[i].StartMin, reservations[i].ampm);
            printf("End Time: %d:%d %s\n", reservations[i].EndTime, reservations[i].Endmin, reservations[i].ampm1);
            printf("Purpose: %s\n", reservations[i].purpose);
            printf("-------------------------\n\n");
        }
    }
}

void DeleteReservation() {
    int index;
    printf("\nEnter the index of the reservation to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    if (index < 1 || index > NumReserves) {
        printf("Invalid index.\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = index - 1; i < NumReserves - 1; ++i) {
        reservations[i] = reservations[i + 1];
    }

    NumReserves--;
    printf("\nReservation deleted successfully.\n\n");
}

//task 2 if-else
void EditReservation() {
    int index;
    printf("\nEnter the index of the reservation to edit: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    if (index < 1 || index > NumReserves) {
        printf("Invalid index.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Editing Reservation %d:\n", index);
    struct Reservation updatedReservation;

    if (NumReserves >= MaxRooms) {
        printf("No more room for reservations.\n");
        return;
    }

    while(1){
        printf("\nEnter the room number (Please enter only three(3) digits): ");
        scanf("%d", &updatedReservation.RoomNumber);

        if(updatedReservation.RoomNumber < 1000 && updatedReservation.RoomNumber >= 100){
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
        }
    } 

    while(1){
        printf("Enter date of use (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        scanf("%d/%d/%d", &updatedReservation.m1,&updatedReservation.d1,&updatedReservation.year);

        if(updatedReservation.m1 > 0 && updatedReservation.m1 < 13 && updatedReservation.d1 > 0 && updatedReservation.d1 <= 31 && updatedReservation.year > 999 && updatedReservation.year <= 9999){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong date format\n");
        }
    }

    while(1){
        printf("Enter start time:\n");
        printf("Enter Hours: ");
        scanf("%d", &updatedReservation.StartTime);
        printf("Enter Minutes: ");
        scanf("%d", &updatedReservation.StartMin);
        printf("Enter AM/PM: ");
        scanf("%s", updatedReservation.ampm);

        if(updatedReservation.StartTime <= 12 && updatedReservation.StartTime > 0 && updatedReservation.StartMin <= 59 && updatedReservation.StartMin > 0){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong time format!\n");
        }
    }

    while(1){
        printf("Enter End time:\n");
        printf("Enter Hours: ");
        scanf("%d", &updatedReservation.EndTime);
        printf("Enter Minutes: ");
        scanf("%d", &updatedReservation.Endmin);
        printf("Enter AM/PM: ");
        scanf("%s", updatedReservation.ampm1);

        if(updatedReservation.EndTime <= 12 && updatedReservation.EndTime > 0 && updatedReservation.Endmin <= 59 && updatedReservation.Endmin > 0){
            break;
        }else{
            printf("Wrong time format!\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Enter purpose of the usage: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(updatedReservation.purpose, MaxPurpose, stdin);
    updatedReservation.purpose[strcspn(updatedReservation.purpose, "\n")] = 0;

    if (CheckOverlap(updatedReservation)) {
        printf("This reservation conflicts with an existing one and cannot be added.\n");
    } else {
        reservations[NumReserves++] = updatedReservation;
        printf("\nReservation added successfully.\n\n");
    }

    reservations[index - 1] = updatedReservation;

    printf("\nReservation updated successfully.\n\n");
}
```

[the error is ampm on 'start time'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpevF.png)

Comment: Can you reduce the code snippet to a [mre]? Just post the code related to displaying the time, not everything else.

Comment: `char ampm[2]` isn't big enough to hold AM or PM. You forgot to add a byte for the null terminator. So you're getting undefined behavior when you overflow the field.

Comment: One of the many coding principles to learn is **DRY**: Don't Repeat Yourself. A considerable portion of the code you've posted is repetitious. This means something as simple as getting around to **fixing** every call to `scanf()` to properly check the function's return code (users won't cooperate with your intent) will take even more time. Copy/paste merely _bloats_ the code. When tempted, don't! Invest the time to do it right the first time. That investment will pay for itself many, many times over.